# Phone (iPhone & Android) only css

Tags: android, iphone, css

I am trying to use some CSS that is exclusively for phones. I have tried to do something like this and seen similar suggestions elsewhere.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1136px)
```

The problem is newer phones (ie iPhone 5) have a resolution greater than not so old tablets (ie, iPad 2). Is there any better way to handle this? I don't want to include the resolution of every known phone as a check. Is a user agent check better?

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to do detection based on User Agent string (it can be forged, there's new UA strings coming out all the time, etc.).  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have CSS that is specific for iPhone but using the above @media it is also applied to an iPad2 which I don't want.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question.  What are you feeding to iPhone that you don't want to give to iPad2 (and why)?

Comment: Because an iPhone 5 has higher DPI I don't want to display the standard version of the page but the mobile version. Otherwise the content is too small to read and hard to navigate.

Comment: There is a media query property for DPI:  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution

Answer (score 0):

There's no correct answer for this but you could use some standard queries.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Answer (score 0):

User agent also can do this, and you can use PHP to do it

Check this out: [Check if PHP-page is accessed from an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322112/check-if-php-page-is-accessed-from-an-ios-device)