# Open iOS App from URL in E-Mail (Custom URL Scheme)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, url-scheme

I want the Links in my E-Mails to open in a 3rd-Party App on iPhones. The Links should also be openable on any computer.

The Links are normal http/https URLs. I am aware of the concept of custom url schemes on iOS. But links with 'myscheme://' in mails won't work on a computer.
The normal approach is to open the website and let it detect if the device is an iPhone and redirect to the url scheme. Problem in this case: Safari won't work on these iPhones. (No way around) Everything happens in an intranet.

Is there a way to register an URL Scheme like Apple Maps does? This is Enterprise Development, so no App Store Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Universal Urls for this. Still needs an internet connection.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you should modify your url with php or javascript that check device model
if url open on iphone/ipad send custom URL schema back and other case send some url for pc

something like this
[Check if PHP-page is accessed from an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322112/check-if-php-page-is-accessed-from-an-ios-device)

Comment: As mentioned in the Question, Safari will not work, and therefore no Websites.