# Php function to check if its android or IOS

Tags: php, android, ios, if-statement

I am looking for a simple way to check if the user is on a android mobile divice or if its on a apple(IOS) divice so I can display the website for them. I found some solutions but I wanna know if there is a simple if/else statement to check that.

Comment: $_SERVER, maybe

Comment: Simple Solution :-> just pass **`use_type=android/IOS`** parameter while calling api and disaplay result based on that

Comment: Posible duplication of:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322112/check-if-php-page-is-accessed-from-an-ios-device)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if PHP-page is accessed from an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322112/check-if-php-page-is-accessed-from-an-ios-device)

Answer (score 0):

I use this package:

https://github.com/hisorange/browser-detect

Install:

`composer require hisorange/browser-detect`

Some functions you might use:

1) `Browser::platformFamily()` // iOS

2) `Browser::browserFamily()` // Chrome Mobile iOS

3) `$browser = Browser::detect();` // Get all details about the visitor's device: