# Detect if device is iOS or Android, and then redirect

Tags: php, html, xml, w3c

So I have a website, and what I want is that when the open my website: www.example.com/download.html I want to first detect if the device is iOS device or Android device, and then redirect to another link, for example www.google.com (just an example). I want different link for different OS. Any tips on how I can manage this? :)

Comment: This question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6322112/7362396

Comment: Alternatively, a quick Google search comes up with a promising looking library if you don't want to put too much of the code in your source: https://github.com/WhichBrowser/Parser-PHP

Answer (score 5):

You can use the user agent string to detect different kinds of devices like so:

```
function androidOrIOS() {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    if(/android/i.test(userAgent)){
        return 'android';
    }
    if(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/i.test(userAgent)){
        return 'ios';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I put this in the download.html?

Comment: Yes, and you can redirect the user with window.location.replace("some link"); or window.location.href = "some link";

Comment: Do I need to add anything else to the html file? Can you also show if the code if it is a computer and not device?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) to determine the type of device

```
function navigate() {
    if((/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent))){
        window.location.href = 'android url ';
    }
    if(/Mobi|iPad|iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        window.location.href = 'ios url ';
    }
}
```

Comment: how widely supported is Navigator?

Comment: It looks to me like searching for "Mobi" in the second `if` is unnecessary, as the first one will already catch that case. Overall it would seem to me like this will not work correctly going by that alone.