# How to avoid the Android keyboard is closed automatically after I click on an Input to type on it?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-softkeyboard, google-chrome-android

My PWA had been working fine for several years until recently. Now, it seems there is a new problem with the keyboard because I cannot type anything at all.

My bug, in my opinion, is related to another well-known issue: "Web apps are resized against our will when we open the keyboard." *(I'm wondering how **Twitter** does since it doesn't resize when I do click on the input)*.

[image: bug]

These are some pieces of my code. I wrote them trying to prevent the app to be resized:

**HTML:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.onresize = function() {
    resizeScreen();
};

function resizeScreen() {
    let scaleVal = window.innerHeight / 600;
    if (window.innerHeight < 514) {
        if (externalContainer === null) {
            let bodyTmp = document.body;
            let divTmp = document.createElement("div");
            divTmp.id = 'externalContainer';
            bodyTmp.insertBefore(divTmp, bodyTmp.firstChild);
        }
        externalContainer = document.getElementById('externalContainer');
        let sContainer = document.getElementById('superContainer');
        externalContainer.append(sContainer);
        externalContainer.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;
        sContainer.style.transformOrigin = "50% 0% 0px";

        setTimeout(function() {
            sContainer.style.transform = `scale(${scaleVal})`;
            setTimeout(function() {
                let cHeight = (1 + scaleVal) * window.innerHeight;
                if (cHeight < 514)
                    cHeight = 514;
                sContainer.style.height = `${cHeight}px`;
            }, 100);
        }, 100);
    } else {
        let sContainer = document.getElementById('superContainer');
        sContainer.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;
        sContainer.style.transformOrigin = "50% 0% 0px";

        setTimeout(function() {
            sContainer.style.transform = `scale(${scaleVal})`;
        }, 100);

        setTimeout(function() {
            if (cmbSpeechType.getBoundingClientRect().width > window.outerWidth)
                sContainer.style.transform = `scale(${scaleVal - (scaleVal - cmbSpeechType.getBoundingClientRect().width / window.outerWidth)})`;
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

In order to fix the "native app" (a custom version that I wrote), I added: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`, but I couldn't find any alternative in JS. I tried to emulate it using `onfocus="window.location.href='#id'; return true;"` but it didn't work. This point about `adjustNothing` has been suggested in [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=404315) since 2014.

I also tried setting a `min-height` in CSS equals to the window height, but it didn't change the problem.

Furthermore, I tried this other crazy idea of making floating the control, it didn't work:

```
txtSpeaker.addEventListener("onfocus", function() {
    window.body.style.zIndex = -1;
    txtSpeaker.style.zIndex = 1000;
});

txtSpeaker.addEventListener("onblur", function() {
    window.body.style.zIndex = "";
    txtSpeaker.style.zIndex = "";
});
```

You can check the full source code here:

https://github.com/FANMixco/toastmasters-timer-material-design

Also, here is the app:

https://fanmixco.github.io/toastmasters-timer-material-design

The main source sections are here:

- [index.html](https://github.com/FANMixco/toastmasters-timer-material-design/blob/master/index.html)
- [timer.js](https://github.com/FANMixco/toastmasters-timer-material-design/blob/master/js/timer.js)

Any idea how to fix this odd issue?

**P.S.:**

This is an **Android-specific** bug because, on iOS and Windows 10, the PWA is working fine. After all, the view is not resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of fixed it by doing the following:

```
function androidOrIOS() {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    if(/android/i.test(userAgent)){
        return 'android';
    }
    if(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/i.test(userAgent)){
        return 'ios';
    }
}

var os = androidOrIOS();

//Only resize if it´s Android
if (os !== "Android") {
    window.onresize = function() {
        resizeScreen();
    };
}


//Change the location of the body based on the location that I "need".
if (os === "Android") {
    txtSpeaker.addEventListener("onfocus", function() {
        let y = document.getElementById("playControl").getBoundingClientRect().y;
        document.body.marginTop = `-${y}px`;
    });
    
    txtSpeaker.addEventListener("onblur", function() {
        document.body.marginTop = '0px';
    });
}
```

The function `androidOrIOS` is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911220/1928691.