# Android iOS deep linking, one domain, several apps

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking

I'm working on several android and ios apps and I'd prefer deep links like this:

```
https://my-domain.com/app1/link1
https://my-domain.com/app1/link2
https://my-domain.com/app2/link1
https://my-domain.com/app2/link2
```

instead of:

```
https://app1.com/link1
https://app1.com/link2
https://app2.com/link1
https://app2.com/link2
```

Is the first approach doable on both platforms? Or should/need I pick the second one and register separate domains for each app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the way you want, but if your apps have different database connections, your backend may become a mess.

I'd recommend you look into subdomains, like

`https://app1.my-domain.com/link1`

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if the user have a Android device or iOS device from your website and build redirection depending which device have the user
[Check if PHP-page is accessed from an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322112/check-if-php-page-is-accessed-from-an-ios-device)

Comment: I meant does android and ios both support deep links on the form https://my-domain.com/app1/link1 etc. I'd prefer not to register a multitude of domains for all apps (I want to use "my-domain.com/appX" instead).