# How do I get my iOS app to work with universal link with safelinks.protection.outlook.com

Tags: outlook, ios-universal-links

I have an app that works fine on Android, and works fine on iOS for non-Outlook clients. In fact, it even works for some Outlook clients. It only fails when the Microsoft Advanced Threat Protection (ATP) is enabled on the recipient's server. This pads my URL within a https://xxxxx.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=**my_url**&data=*to_email_address_and_data*

I have noticed that if I click on the Apple Store link that we send in an email that gets ATP applied, it opens Safari, Safari prompts

> Open in "App Store"?

then the App Store opens.

What do I need on my website to make this happen?

I don't believe that this is a duplicate of [Android Deep Linking with emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227610/android-deep-linking-with-emails)
as I don't have an issue with Android.

Answer (score -1):

OK. Worked this out.

Create a URL Scheme in your Info.plist
In index.[html,php,js]

Test for iOS device (see [Check if PHP-page is accessed from an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322112/check-if-php-page-is-accessed-from-an-ios-device))

```
<?php
header('Location: '."newUrlScheme://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
?>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate / be more specific about "Create a URL Scheme in your Info.plist In index.[html,php,js]" -- that could help others (like me) to understand better what is it exactly that you've done